# How to obtain a MultiPart file AND form data in 1 request with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, postman

I have this controller below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestBody Campaign inputCampaign,
            Principal principal) {
```

It works fine whenever I do not have the `@RequestBody Campaign inputCampaign`, which is an object that holds data for a user's video, and will upload the video and save it to the proper directory.

However, I would like to take the file they uploaded AND the form data associated with their campaign in 1 request so that way I can save relevant information about their campaign (such as the title, description, etc...).

When I try to use the controller above, and I try to send a request in Postman, I get this error below:

```
  "timestamp": 1473349676109,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryTVc9eDC2a2elulOx;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/dashboard/upload"
```

Here's my Postman request setup:

[image: Postman Request]

How can I send campaign form data and the file in one request? The campaign object has many fields so I don't want to have to put `@RequestParam` in the controller parameters for each form field. Jackson should automatically map the properties.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to send to that RequestMapping?

Comment: @px06 currently allowed to send jpg, png, and mp4. They all work when I take out `@RequestBody Campaign inputCampaign` but I want to be able to receive form data with the file which will automatically be mapped to the `Campaign` object (Spring's Jackson library does this automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Jake.

Did you try by removing both of the annotations?

For demonstration purpose, I did a simple mapping as below:

```
@PutMapping("/file/{fileName}")
@ResponseBody
public String[] postFile(
        @PathVariable(name = "fileName") String fileName,
        List<MultipartFile> files,
        User user
) throws IOException {
    return new String[]{
            fileName,
            user.getUsername(),
            files.stream()
                    .map((f)-> f.getOriginalFilename())
                    .reduce("", (e, f)->e.concat(f).concat(", "))
    };
}
```

where I attempted to upload few files into `List<MultipartFile> files`.

[Sample output from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zv5Q.jpg)

As shown in the image, both `files` and `user` data was mapped automatically and there is no need for any annotations.

Hope it helps.